# Sending email to Participants of an inactive Event

Tags: civievent, email

Based on a report I got today: Let's say we have an Event which has eight people registered, but the event has been cancelled. We set the event to "Inactive" and then click on "Participants" beside the event in the Manage Events page to get a list of all the registered participants. The list comes up as expected, so we select all and choose "Email (Send now)" from the actions menu.

[image: Email send now]

Then the email screen comes up, and instead of eight registered participants, we have 15 people listed in the email list, and I'm not sure where the extras are from:

[image: Email now]

Can anyone help me sort out what is going on here?

Note that if I make the event active again it works as expected, so we have that workaround for sending emails to these folks.